# WinAppDriver:-Reference to type 'IFindsByTagName' claims it is defined in 'WebDriver', 'IFindsByClassName' , 'IFindsById' claims it is defined'

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, winappdriver

1- Developer mode active
2- WinApp installed properly
3- Nuget appium dependency installed
4- Microsoft visual  studio 2022

---

using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;

```
namespace WebAppDriverNUNIT
{
    public class Tests
    {
        public const string DriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/";
        //private const string CalculatorAppId ="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
        
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe");
            AppiumOptions Options = new AppiumOptions();
           // Options.AdditionalCapability("app", "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"); // for Universal Windows Platform apps
            Options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
            Options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
            Options.SetLoggingPreference(OpenQA.Selenium.LogType.Server, OpenQA.Selenium.LogLevel.All);
            var driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(DriverUrl), Options);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            Assert.IsNotNull(driver);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            driver.CloseApp();


        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are nugets and versions are you using WinAppDriver, Appium, Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

For now, WinAppDriver is not supported by Selenium 4 due WinAppDriver is not yet W3C compliant.
@pawansinghncr You should install Selenium Pre 4.0 (e.g. version 3.141.0) for all Selenium libraries. Also, set up an appropriate Appium Nuget.

Comment: I'm facing below error after downgrading my Selenium to 3.141.0                             "Detected package downgrade: Selenium.WebDriver from 4.0.0-beta2 to 3.141.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. "

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade (Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support) nuget packages to 3.141.0....your issue will be resolved.

Comment: If You do have knowledge on the matter, please explain so the asker understand the problem instead of just giving the solution, which may or may not be applicable depending on what other projects may or may not be changeable in their references also giving why is much more than a workaround, like downgrading in the most cases is.

Comment: It's quite a simple explanation.  There was a breaking change - methods were removed. That's all.

Comment: Hi, I get the same error when I use Appium 4.4.5 with Selenium 4.9.1 in line where I initialize Appium Driver for android -         static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> appiumDriver;
Is there any solution to this ?