# Selenium 4 not compatible with WinAppDriver

Tags: selenium, winappdriver

I updated Selenium in Visual Studio to the latest version (Selenium 4) and noticed WinAppDriver is not compatible with the latest Selenium throwing errors.
Aimed to replace DesiredCapabilities by Options but still getting error on WindowsElement .
I was wondering if anyone can help me to fix the code and get it working.

The code I have in Visual Studio:

```
Process.Start(@WinDriver);
AppiumOptions appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "Root");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
var session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), 
appiumOptions);
```

and this is the error message VS is displaying:

[image]

Appium.Weddriver is on version 4.3.2

and

Windows.WebDriver is on 4.5

Thanks,

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74632066/461499

Answer (score 1):

WinAppDriver is still not (yet?) compliant with selenium version upper than 4.0.0.

Downgrading the Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support NugetPackages to 3.141.0 will solve this issue.

You can find more details in this more recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921159/winappdriver-reference-to-type-ifindsbytagname-claims-it-is-defined-in-webdr)