# Appium WinAppDriver and Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium, appium, winappdriver, selenium4

I am struggling to use get WinAppDriver to open an application, my maven imports are as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.9.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am opening the application with the following code:

```
  WindowsDriver adminApp = null;
    DesiredCapabilities winCap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    winCap.setCapability("app", "C:\\Program Files\\Traka\\Traka Web Admin\\TrakaWebAdmin.exe");
    winCap.setCapability("ms:experimental-webdriver", true);
    winCap.setCapability("platformName", "windows");
    winCap.setCapability("automationName", "windows");
    adminApp = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"), winCap);
```

every time I run this I get the following error:

```
{"status":100,"value":
 {"error":"invalid argument","message":"Bad capabilities. Specify either app or appTopLevelWindow to create a session"}}
```

However when I change my selenium version to:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can open the application, I am not sure if I am missing anything, can anyone help?

Comment: Just for further context, I can't simply regress to selenium 3.141.59 as I have a lot of tests that depend on Selenium 4 and a refactor to regress to an older version isn't really an option for me.

Comment: Appears WinAppDriver hasn't been updated since 2020. I'm in the same boat. Upgraded to Selenium 4 months ago. Going back isn't an option.

Comment: Any updates? I have the same issue :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are able to get the WinAppDriver to open an application with Selenium **v3.141.59** but not with Selenium **v4.6.0** is due to some major changes between major versions 7 and 8 of Appium java client.

As per the [v7-to-v8-migration-guide](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md#strict-w3c-specification-compatibility) from W3C specification compatibility perspective:

> - Java client now supports Selenium 4, which also means it is strictly W3C compliant. Old JWP-based servers are not supported anymore, and it
>   won't be possible to use the new client version with them.
>   Capabilities that enforce the usage of JWP protocol on Appium drivers
>   don't have any effect anymore.
> - The recommended way to provide capabilities for driver creation is to use specific option builders inherited from [BaseOptions
>   class](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/remote/options/BaseOptions.java).
>   For example
>   [XCUITestOptions](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/ios/options/XCUITestOptions.java)
>   to create a XCUITest driver instance or
>   [UiAutomator2Options](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/android/options/UiAutomator2Options.java)
>   to create an UiAutomator2 driver instance. If there is no
>   driver-specific options class for your driver then either use
>   BaseOptions builder as the base class to define your capabilities or
>   request driver developers to add one. Do not use DesiredCapabilities
>   class for this purpose in W3C context. Check [unit
>   tests](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/drivers/options/OptionsBuildingTest.java)
>   for more examples on how to build driver options.

Moreover in the discussion [Unable to Initiate Session with WinAppDriver](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1592#issuecomment-1109188197) [@Appium](https://github.com/appium) maintainer *`@KazuCocoa`*  mentioned that:

> > The WinAppDriver requires selenium v3 based client for now since Selenium v4 requires W3C spec protocol that is not supported by WinAppDriver yet.

Further in the discussion [Support for Selenium 4](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1839) *`@pm90pl`* confirmed:

> > Yeah. So, the current version is not compatible with W3C WebDriver standard what makes it incompatible with Selenium 4. There is no clear roadmap for WAD and it's not open source so you have to deal it on your own.
> > Upgrading Selenium without checking WAD compatibility was a mistake. Sorry.

---

### Conclusion

The only viable option to execute the WinAppDriver based test is to backport to ***Selenium v3.141.59***

Comment: The WinAppDriver project hasn't even been touched in 4 years.  It sucks we have to choose between Selenium and the WinAppDriver now.

Answer (score 0):

As per github discussion on WinAppDriver:

> The WinAppDriver requires selenium v3 based client for now since
> Selenium v4 requires W3C spec protocol that is not supported by
> WinAppDriver yet.

- https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1592#issuecomment-1109188197

Comment: edited and added context. @Yunnosch

Comment: It has been requested: https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1839

Answer (score 0):

You can try complying with the W3C standard for capabilities in which case you will need `appium:app`, `appium:ms:experimental-webdriver` and `appium:automationName` as capabilities and see if this helps. `platformName` is compliant with W3C so no change there. For more information you can refer to [this](https://appiumpro.com/editions/123-migrating-to-appium-20-part-1-capability-prefixes)